# Why cant I see anything at listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have a DB which I'm trying to connect to listView (by CursorAdapter)

I follow: [Populating a ListView with a CursorAdapter](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter)
but I'm missing somthing, because I cant see anything at the listview.

I have an activity which contains fragment:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmnet_main_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="keepInTouch.today.MainListFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main_list" />
```

The fragment looks:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="keepInTouch.today.MainListFragment">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mainFragmentListTitle"
        android:background="#e43d3d"
        android:textColor="#371b1b" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvKits"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Each list item looks:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The cursorAdpter looks:

```
public class ContactsCursorAdapter  extends CursorAdapter{

    public ContactsCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View  newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.today_view, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KitSqliteOpenHelper.KEY_KIT_TITLE));
        tvTitle.setText(title);
    }
}
```

in the activty onCreate (and after update) I'm calling this function:

```
   private void updateListView() {

        MainListFragment mainListFragment = (MainListFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmnet_main_list);
        Cursor cursor = KitSqliteOpenHelper.getInstance(this).getAllRawKits();
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textV);
        textView.setText("Total: " + cursor.getCount());
        mainListFragment.updateListView();
    }



 public Cursor getAllRawKits()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String QUERY_SELECT_ALL = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s", TABLE_KIT);
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY_SELECT_ALL, null);
        return cursor;
    }


public class MainListFragment extends Fragment {

    ContactsCursorAdapter contactsCursorAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_list, container, false);
        createContactsCursorAdapter(view);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_list, container, false);
    }


    private void createContactsCursorAdapter(View view)
    {
        Cursor cursor = KitSqliteOpenHelper.getInstance(getActivity()).getAllRawKits();
        contactsCursorAdapter = new ContactsCursorAdapter(getActivity(), cursor);
        ListView lvItems = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvKits);
        lvItems.setAdapter(contactsCursorAdapter);
    }

    public void updateListView() {
        Cursor cursor = KitSqliteOpenHelper.getInstance(getActivity()).getAllRawKits();
        contactsCursorAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);
        contactsCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //contactsCursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }
}
```

I see that I have 6 items (cursor size) but none of elements are viewed at the listView

I had tried to replace (for debugging only):

```
  tvTitle.setText(title);
```

with   `tvTitle.setText("test");`

in the ContactsCursorAdapter, bindView
and I got same results...

After more debugging it seems that newView and bindView from ContactsCursorAdapter are not called. why ?

The mainactivity looks:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    public MemoResultReciver memoResultReciver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        KitSqliteOpenHelper.getInstance(this);
        updateListView();
    }




    static final int PICK_CONTACT_DETAILS = 1;
    public void onClickButton(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChooseContactActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT_DETAILS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Check which request we're responding to
        if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_DETAILS) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textV);

                KitContactInfo kitContactInfo = data.getParcelableExtra("KitInfo");
                String kitName = kitContactInfo.title;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), kitName + " was added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateListView();
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateListView() {

        MainListFragment mainListFragment = (MainListFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmnet_main_list);
        Cursor cursor = KitSqliteOpenHelper.getInstance(this).getAllRawKits();
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textV);
        textView.setText("Total: " + cursor.getCount());
        mainListFragment.updateListView();
    }

    public void scheduleAlarm(KitContactInfo kitContactInfo)
    {
        // Construct an intent that will execute the AlarmReceiver
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SchdulerBroadcastReceiver.class);
        udateMemoService(intent, kitContactInfo.contactPhone, kitContactInfo.contactName);

        // Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
        final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, SchdulerBroadcastReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,  intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calander = Calendar.getInstance();
        calander.set(kitContactInfo.year ,kitContactInfo.month, kitContactInfo.day, kitContactInfo.hour, kitContactInfo.min, 0);
        alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calander.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
    }


    private void udateMemoService(Intent intent,String number, String msg) {
        intent.putExtra("PhoneNumber", number);
        intent.putExtra("Message", msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you call 'updateListView()' ?

Comment: and what is in your 'getAllRawKits' ?

Comment: In the activity which contains the fragment (which contains the listview)

Comment: try changing your list items height to wrap_content

Comment: Try giving the listview the following properties instead : android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"

Comment: same results...

Comment: Can you confrim that the bindView method is called ?

Comment: you are right, the 2 functions of ContactsCursorAdapter are not called, why ?

Comment: Post your full activity class craeting the fragment if you can so that we could investigate deeper.

Comment: Have you tried not using a Fragment and doing this all from an Activity with a ListView (for debugging purposes)?

Comment: When trying to do this without fragment, it works. you know why ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't see enough info since I can't see the whole code implementation but there is something to have in count and maybe is the problem, when you are onCreate() in the activity the fragment is not attached to the activity yet so when you call the `updateListView()` in your fragment from the `onCreate()` the `getActivity()`  should be returning a null value.

As I am telling you I am not sure from this, it would be good if you added the whole Activity implementation, are you sure you are creating and attaching the fragment to the activity correctly since the problem could be related to the activity displaying the fragment and not the `ListView` itself.

Comment: I can see the text of "mainFragmentListTitle" (the element above the listview in the fragment) so I not sure you are right

Comment: Then check if changing you list item layout height to wrap_content, if it does not work try calling your adapter creation and updating in the onCreateView method to verify the problem does not have to do with lifecycle conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your MainActivity updateListView by :

```
private void updateListView() {

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction f = fm.beginTransaction();
        f.add(R.id.R.id.fragmnet_main_list, new MainListFragment());
        f.commit();


        MainListFragment mainListFragment = (MainListFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmnet_main_list);
        Cursor cursor = KitSqliteOpenHelper.getInstance(this).getAllRawKits();
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textV);
        textView.setText("Total: " + cursor.getCount());
        mainListFragment.updateListView();
    }
}
```